# using $in in find() query in casbah

Tags: scala, casbah

I'm trying to use casbah's fluid querying in find().

My data is like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d7b26efc58bf2b18f14d9cd"), "srcID" : [ "/m/05zppz" ], "relation" : [ "/location/location/people_born_here" ], "dstID" : [ "/m/06sfnt9" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d7b26efc58bf2b19014d9cd"), "srcID" : [ "/m/05zppz" ], "relation" : [ "/location/location/people_born_here" ], "dstID" : [ "/m/06fqp8" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d7b26efc58bf2b19114d9cd"), "srcID" : [ "/m/05zppz" ], "relation" : [ "/location/location/people_born_here" ], "dstID" : [ "/m/06_7xfd" ] }
```

I wrote the following code to query this:

```
val srcIDs:List[String] = List("/m/05zppz", "/m/06sfnt9")
val query = "srcID" $in srcIDs
```

the code segment does not compile and reports this error:

```
error: value $in is not a member of java.lang.String
query = ("srcID" $in srcIDs)
```

The casbah documentation has the above syntax for $in, but it doesn't seem to work.
How to make the $in query work? As a matter of fact, I could not get any fluid query with Casbah's DSL to work and they fail giving the same error msg. Please help!

Comment: Just an FYI since you are new to the site: a little bit of formatting goes a long way. You can see a preview of your post as you type, too!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `$in` is not a method defined on strings. Most likely Casbah defines an implicit conversion from `String` objects to instances of a class that contain the method `$in`. The implicit conversion needs to be `import`ed into scope before it can be used.

Could you point us to the Casbah documentation that introduces the `$in` method? That's where we will find what needs to be imported.

(For the experts: isn't `$` supposed to be reserved for compiler generated fields?)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it! You reply was very helpful. I had missed the import statement needed for implicit conversion and hence it was treating it as a String.

I included `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._` and it works like a charm now. Thanks for the hint!